# VirtualBox Snapshot - How to stop them to grow and take more and more space?

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

I'm using Genymotion with Oracle VirtualBox, however i do have 250 GB SSD and i'm facing an issue with ( Snapshots ) I googled & searched here, I couldn't find any possible way to disable Auto snap-shots, as i don't need it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy a new Genymotion virtual device, a snapshot called `factory-backup` is automatically created so that paid users can reset the device to the factory state via the Launcher GUI. If you don't want this snapshot, then just use VirtualBox Manager directly to delete it once the device is deployed. From the Manager interface, with the VM in question selected, click on *Snapshots* in the upper right corner, then select `factory-backup` and hit the delete button. As far as I can tell, there is no provision for disabling this initial snapshot creation via the Genymotion Launcher.

In my experiences, Genymotion does not create further snapshots during the lifetime of a virtual device, only upon initial deployment. But if you are experiencing this, then I recommend again using the VirtualBox Manager to set the *Snapshot Folder* to a non-existent directory once the device is deployed. This can be done via *Settings->General->Advanced* for each device you wish to disable snapshotting.

Comment: Virtual box not allow set a invalid folder to snapshots. And when I delete a snapshot from virtualbox, that snapshot is just "merged", so disk space not change